# In Mac Terminal, What's the meaning of "@" symbol at the end of premissions_parameters?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, ls

In Mac's terminal, tap "ls -l", I find one file's description like this:

```
-rw-------@ 1 name  staff  1866 12  5 14:48 myfile
```

what's the meaning of "@"?

Comment: It means the file has extended attributes. They can be displayed with `xattr -l myfile`.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l

Comment: I got it, thanks @philant and Bill.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @philant said "It means the file has extended attributes. They can be displayed with xattr -l myfile." For more detailed, go look this link [most detailed description about ls command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l)